# Dispute with overseas logistics company (USA) - how to sue an international company?

Tags: united-states, international, shipping

I live in the UK and sell stuff on Amazon. Last year I used a logistics company in the US to help me deliver my products from China to the US.

They gave me a quote for $1850 which I paid. 8 weeks later, they gave me another bill of $1550 for extra charges. This dispute went on and was not fully resolve, yet they charged my card on file a few months later.

I'm trying to resolve this matter with them, but if push comes to shove, how can I sue them here? Will I have to pay a lawyer in the US? I'm determined to get my money back.

Comment: Did you dispute the charge with the card issuer?

Comment: Does the company do business in the UK?

Comment: I'm actually OP ( dont know why I can't log in as that account). But to answer your questions - 1) They charged my account in December, and when I called my bank, they immediately refunded me the amount. I foolishly thought the dispute was resolved so I left it at that. Little did I know that there's a 4 month time frame for you to resolve that dispute, and if you don't respond within that time frame visa charges your card. That time frame is passed now so trying to get the money back through my bank is now out of the question (I'm super angry at myself for this). 2) I don't do any business in

Comment: @JosephLiu - use the contact us form at the bottom of the page to merge your accounts - looks like you didn't register the account you used to sign up

Comment: The question is not about you doing business, it's about the other company doing business. If they do business in the UK, you can sue them in the UK and have a better change of collecting. It also might matter what the relevant law of UK vs. US is (one might afford you greater protection).

Comment: @user6726 They are an international company, but don't seem to haven an office in the UK. They do have an office in Hong Kong though and that's where my company is registered in. Would that be of any use?

Comment: Is there a choice of court agreement? Is there an arbitral agreement? What does the contract say which entity your contracting party is? Did you enter into the contract with that entity directly, or through one of its branch offices?

Comment: I don't think they actually have set up an entity in Hong Kong. I entered into the contract with the main office in San Francisco

Answer (score 1):

Why would you sue them? Have your credit card company reverse the charge as disputed and force them to sue you.

Comment: "Have" is a bit strong: you can *ask* the card company to reverse the charge and if they agree they will, but it is not automatic.